# How to change Material UI stepper background color if there is an error in a step

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, material-ui

I am using Material UI's stepper component and trying to set the background color of the stepper if there is an error. However, not sure how to do so. I was able to set the background color for steps that have been completed and that was done in here:

Answer (score 0):

Just use the css override the lib provides

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({ error: { ... } }))

const MyComponent = props => {
    const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
    const classes = useStyles()

    // just apply a conditional class to the root to make the background
    // any color you want
    return <Stepper classes={{ root: isError ? classes.error : '' }}>
        ...
    </ Stepper>
}
```